# Prove that $(x + \sqrt[3]{abc})^3 \le (x + a)(x + b)(x + c) \le ( x + \frac{a + b + c}{3})^3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, holder-inequality, jensen-inequality

Let $x,$ $a,$ $b,$ $c$ be nonnegative real numbers. Prove that
$$(x + \sqrt[3]{abc})^3 \le (x + a)(x + b)(x + c) \le \left( x + \frac{a + b + c}{3} \right)^3.$$

I know that this problem is a RHS-AM-GM-HM problem, but I am unsure how to solve it. I think that the leftmost part is AM, but that is as far as I was able to get. I also think that taking the cube root of everything might change it into something more manageable, but I am still unsure about that. 
Can anyone help me with this or give me tips about how to solve it? Thank you.

Comment: What does RHS stand for?

Comment: Try [HUYGEN’S INEQUALITY](https://mathematicaldreams.wordpress.com/2010/02/20/work-013/).

Comment: **Please do not discuss this problem!**  This is an active homework problem.

To the original poster: I realize that homework may be challenging. If you wish to receive some help from the staff or other students, I encourage you to use the resources that the online classes provide, such as the Message Board.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

$$F=(x+a)(x+b)(x+c)=x^3+(a+b+c)x^2+(ab+bc+ca)x+abc~~~~(1)$$ By AM-GM 
$$F \ge x^3 + 3(abc)^{1/3} x^2+3(abc)^{2/3} x+ abc= (x+(abc)^{1/3})~~~~(2)$$
Using $$\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{3} \ge (ab+bc+ca)$$ and AM-GM  in (1), we get
$$F \le x^3+3 \frac{(a+b+c)}{3} x^2 +3\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{9}x+ \left(\frac{a+b+c}{3}\right)^3 = \left(x+\frac{a+b+c}{3}\right)^3$$

Answer (score 2):

Using AM
$$\left( x + \frac{a + b + c}{3} \right)^3=
\left(\frac{(x+a) + (x+b) + (x+c)}{3} \right)^3\overset{AM}{\geq} \\
\left(\sqrt[3]{(x+a)(x+b)(x+c)}\right)^3=
(x+a)(x+b)(x+c)$$
Using [HUYGEN’S INEQUALITY](https://mathematicaldreams.wordpress.com/2010/02/20/work-013/) (which is easy to prove using AM-GM)
$$(x+a)(x+b)(x+c)=x^3\left(1+\frac{a}{x}\right)\left(1+\frac{b}{x}\right)\left(1+\frac{c}{x}\right)\geq\\
x^3\left(1+\sqrt[3]{\frac{a}{x}\frac{b}{x}\frac{c}{x}}\right)^3=
\left(x+\sqrt[3]{abc}\right)^3$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint for the LHS:

$$3 = \sum_{a,b,c}\dfrac{x}{x+a}+\sum_{a,b,c}\dfrac{a}{x+a}\geq\text{Do AM-GM here}.$$

RHS is more trivial than this as it is just exactly one application of AM-GM in disguise.